# Do you get to keep your old nefesh and ruach when you convert?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, zohar, practical-kabbalah

According to our tradition, converts acquire a "new soul" in, or upon emergence from, the conversion mikvah. (Not sure of the original source for this--[it may be the Zohar](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Tx7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=conversion%20%22new%20soul%22&source=bl&ots=Wi68rVLYX2&sig=9YeYmylHAgP0XAqpskPXEj0ZQ94&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXw7P4gpfQAhUH9GMKHdxVDzsQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=conversion%20%22new%20soul%22&f=false)--but there are countless secondary sources.) Accordingly, they change their names, and lose most components of halachic relationship with their birth-parents. But is(n't) the "new soul" just a new Jewish soul, a נשמה, in addition to the convert's preexisting nefesh and ruach? Does(n't) the convert keep the nefesh and ruach he was born with? If so, why would the convert's name, and particularly parents, have to change?

Comment: `but there are countless secondary sources.` editing an example in would be nice. || `Accordingly, they change their names` Many converts don't change their names. Even if they do, I doubt this is because of spiritual change. They probably just want to better fit into their communities, and / or confirm their identity shift. || `and lose most components of halachic relationship with their birth-parents` Again, I don't know why this should be pegged on this "new-soul". The Talmud, the source for this law, does not AFAIK peg it on a new soul.

Comment: `Does(n't) the convert keep the nefesh and ruach he was born with? If so, why would the convert's name, and particularly parents, have to change` Even if the practice of changing one's name, or even the halakha of severance of halakhic biological ties with one's erstwhile relatives, is pegged on a new-soul, what is so difficult? Why assume that these should be based on the nefesh and ruach, rather than the neshama?

Comment: @mevaqesh Your identification of logical holes in my question is, as usual, correct. But let me suggest that a question is not an argument, and that the weak points of a question may in fact be the question itself

Comment: First of all, thank you for your characterization of my comments. If indeed, the questionable assumptions are the question itself, which ones should users address? Does we see no evidence that name change and / halakhic change are based on a new soul, qualify? This is not the optimal since sources are encouraged, but it it can be hard to source a negative...

Comment: Something to think about that may help answer this question - in the morning prayer of "Elokai Netzor", we say, "In the future you will take (my soul) from me, and return it to me in the future." I.e. - the same soul that you were born with is returned to you in *Olam Haba*. There are a number of teachings that say that a Gentile who observes the 7 mitzvoth, has a share in Olam Haba. So, "equating" these ideas. I'm assuming that a Gentile would also have his same soul returned to him in Olam Haba. So, I don't think he gets a new one upon conversion. My analysis on this.

Comment: @DanF That prayer seems to refer to the resurrection of the dead. _olam haba_ doesn't necessarily refer to the resurrection of the dead.

Comment: According to saadia gaon and the rambam, the three terms for the soul are just ways a single unitary soul manifests itself. I'm not sure it makes much sense to say you keep the same nefesh and ruah but get a new neshama.

Comment: This question is very interesting.  I always thought that to see conversion as an organ transplant is nothing else than concrete thinking.  Your efforts to conceptualize this as an addition is beautiful. BTW concerning Teshuva David Hamelech was seeking  creation of heart and ruach